# How to import reasonably big blob into Oracle?

Tags: oracle, blob

I have a reasonably big blob (~128K) that I need to import into Oracle database. While it's size was below 2K I succesfully used following approach:

```
to_blob(hextoraw ('00001111000011110000111100000111100001111000011110' ||
  '00001111000011110000111100000111100001111000011110' ||
  '00001111000011110000111100000111100001111000011110' ||
  '00001111000011110000111100000111100001111000011110' ||
  '00001111000011110000111100000111100001111000011110'))
```

It broke working with following error when amount of data exceeded some threshold:

> SQL Error: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

How do I fix it? Unfortunatelly loading data from file is not an option here, due to certain process restrictions.

Comment: You could use dbms_lob.write_append()

Comment: Can't you use simple bind variable?

Comment: Load, ok but from where?